# Laptop Display Goes Crazy

Tags: windows-10, laptop, battery

I have a 7 year old Dell XPS13 laptop. Since it was a better than average laptop and I was still happy with the performance, last year I upgraded the SSD and installed Windows 10.

The display occasionally goes crazy. But, it only happens on battery power. And, it usually happens when I move the mouse, it won't happen if I'm not touching it. It always fixes itself after a few seconds. But, moving the mouse again will often cause it to reoccur.

I made sure that the display driver was the latest. A driver issue might behave like this, but why does it only occur when I am on battery power?

Here is a phone capture. My desktop is normally blue. Sometimes the entire screen is severely distorted. It was like this for a few seconds, then it fixed itself.

One possible solution is to get a new battery. I might do this if there was some anecdotal evidence supporting this solution.

[image]

EDIT:

Screenshot is OK.

Still happens if power cable is plugged into PC, but unplugged from wall.

Comment: That appears to be a hardware issue (display).  You might be able to find parts that on cheap by purchasing a identical nonworking laptop for parts.

Comment: Unlikely, but... could the physical act of plugging in the battery connector nudge something slightly? Try running with the PS cable plugged into the laptop, but with the PS unplugged from the wall. Also, check power settings under battery vs. AC.

Comment: Dell recognized an issue and released an updated graphics driver back in January 2016. I don't know your model number but if you go to Dell's support you could probably find the updates for your BIOS and graphics display.

Comment: Quick test. Take a photo, also take a screenshot. If the break-up is on the photo but not on the screenshot, you have a hardware issue. It does look like a cable issue to me.

Comment: Is it even possible that when the battery is plugged in the system heat up a lot and after many years the display cable got damaged. Have you checked temperature while battery is plugged?

Comment: If this doesn't happen when the battery is unplugged, you should test your graphics card performance when plugged into AC. I use heaven unigine benchmark. If your screen doesn't show any signs of craziness when doing the benchmark, the problem is probably your battery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found several possible solutions online. It only occurs on Dell XPS L321X laptops.

Apparently, the video driver is not fully compatible with Windows 10. This is why it started occurring after I upgraded to Win10. Since the issue is sporadic and can't be repeated on-demand, the correlation was not obvious.

1. Re-install the video driver in Win8 compatibility mode.

https://www.dell.com/community/XPS/Dell-XPS-13-working-fix-for-distorted-screen-in-Windows-10/td-p/7359860

This did not fix the issue for me.

2. Set the display refresh rate to 40 Hz. Display Settings -> Advanced Display Settings -> Properties.

This seems to have fixed the issue. I don't know if #1 is necessary also, I am not going to mess with success.

3. Wipe the HD and re-install everything. Some people swear that this fixed their issue, but this could also be Dell's standard answer to unknown issues. I did not try this. Mine was a fresh install on a new HD not too long ago, so I am not motivated to try this.